# Present progressive with currently

Tags: progressive-aspect

> Nothing new to report and currently I only ocassionally get anything new in.

Why it is not present progressive for "**get**" as it is not a habit? Is it because  of **currently** which  means a short period?

Comment: You'd better wait some time before accepting my answer (or any answer, for that matter). I'm not a native speaker. Wait until those recover from the arrival of 2016. They might post better answers. (0:

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be okay to use the progressive form here. Quoting from [Grammaring](http://www.grammaring.com/present-continuous-for-temporary-habitual-actions-in-the-present),

> The present continuous is used to express repeated or habitual actions in the present that are temporary and may or may not actually be happening at the time of speaking:
>
> Lucy is **taking** piano lessons *these days*.
>   Are you still **seeing** that guy from the hiking club?

---

> Why it is not present progressive for "get" as it is not a habit? Is it because of currently which means a short period?

Maybe because the speaker sees this pattern as not a temporary thing, but something that might be taking place for quite some time yet.

Maybe his last "report" was a long time ago, and he is reporting on a pattern that has become quite established, from his standpoint.